# Slow file transferring in EC2 of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance in AWS, which is t2.medium. File transferring from a local system to my instance through ssh is very slow - it starts from 1MB/s and after a few seconds drops to 50KB/s. It's really annoying that I couldn't transfer files properly.

Also I have a web server on this instance, which this slow file transferring causes serious problems in uploading files to instance.

I'm wondering if there's any way to solve this problem?

Comment: A common way to transfer data is to use the AWS CLI to upload from your local computer to an Amazon S3 bucket. Then, you can SSH to the EC2 instance and use the AWS CLI to download from the S3 bucket. This should be significantly faster than transferring via SSH because the AWS CLI can perform multi-threaded transfers to take advantage of your full bandwdith.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking. What do you mean by "uploading from webservers"? Uploading _how?_

Comment: I'm developing a web server using flask on my instance - users need to submit their data to the server through a HTML page, and the data will be saved on my instance. But it takes a long time for files to be uploaded on the server